# Como trocar uma div de lugar com script?

Tags: javascript, script, div

Por exemplo eu tenho na página:

```
<div class="geral"></div>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

<div class="geral-2"></div>
```

Como colocar a segunda DIV em baixo da primeira com script ficando assim?

```
<div class="geral"></div>
<div class="geral-2"></div>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Ps: Não tenho acesso ao código base por isso precisa mover usando script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode "copiar" a `div geral-2` com um `outerHTML`  define ou retorna o elemento HTML e todo o seu conteúdo, incluindo a tag inicial, seus atributos e a tag final. Então remover a antiga `geral-2` e com um `insertAdjacentHTML` você insere a copiada depois da `div geral`.

```js
var geral1 = document.querySelector('.geral')
var geral2 = document.querySelector('.geral-2')
var copy = geral2.outerHTML
geral2.remove()

geral1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', copy)

console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="geral"></div>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

<div class="geral-2"></div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Sobre o insertAdjecentHTML caso não o conheça [insertAdjacentHTML - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!